# Many intersections of neighborhoods are nonempty in topological spaces.

Tags: general-topology

I am reading Mendelson's point set topology. I am curious about this example he gives:

"Given two distinct points $x$ and $y$ respectively, such that $N \cap M = \emptyset$. This statement is false in many topological spaces. For example, let $ Y = \{a,b\}$, $a \neq b$ and let $\tau = \{\emptyset, \{a\}, Y \}$ so that $(Y,\tau)$ is a topological space. Then the only neighborhood of $b$ is $Y$. Thus for each neighborhood $N$ of $a$ and each neighborhood $M$ of $b$, $N \cap M = N \cap Y = N \neq \emptyset$."

I understand why the only neighborhood of $b$ is $Y$ in this topological space. What about the neighborhoods of $a$? Would that be the singleton set $\{a\}$ itself and $Y$?

Comment: Yes, $N=\{a\}$ or $N=Y$

Comment: Thank you  <3 @J.W.Tanner

Comment: Could you quote the complete paragraph (and possibly give the page) you are interested in? The sentence "Given two distinct points $x$ and $y$ respectively, such that $N \cap M = \emptyset$" does not make any sense without the definition of $M$ and $N$.

Comment: The space $(Y,\tau )$ is called Sierpinski space. It is an example or counter-example for many topological properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the only open subset of $Y$ that contains $b$ is $Y$ (the other open sets are $\{a\}$ and $\emptyset$, which do not), so it's also the only neighbourhood of $b$. A set $N$ is a neighbourhood of $a$ iff $a \in N$ because $\{a\}$ is already open. So $\{a\}$ and $Y$ are the only neighbourhoods of $a$. So a neighbourhood of $b$ and one for $a$ always intersect in $a$ at least.